# Recursive function cleartimeout not working in special case

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

My function updates content via ajax and refreshes 5 seconds after success. If the user wants to get a refresh immidiately in between he can click a button.

My problem is sometimes (when auto refresh and user refresh are fired almost in the same time) clearTimeout is not working and the function starts to run twice.

```
var rotate=0;

function refresh(){
    $.ajax({
    ...,
    success : function(data){
        $('#content-to-insert').html(data);
        rotate = setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
        }
    });
}

$('#user-refresh-btn').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(rotate);
    refresh();
});
```

What can i do? Thank you much for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I see an issue if an ajax call is already in progress and then the user presses the refresh button.  Then you would get both the ajax call already in progress and a new one started by the refresh button.  You can fix that like this:

```
var rotate;
var refreshInProgress = false;

function refresh(){
    refreshInProgress = true;
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success : function(data){
            refreshInProgress = false;
            $('#content-to-insert').html(data);
            rotate = setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
        }
        complete: function() {
            // catch any other ways the ajax call might finish (such as error)
            refreshInProgress = false;
        }
    });
}

$('#user-refresh-btn').click(function(){
    if (refreshInProgress) return;
    clearTimeout(rotate);
    refresh();
});
```

Comment: @user3365693 - since you're new here, I wonder if you understand how StackOverflow is supposed to work?  When you get your question answered, you should select the answer that best helped you by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will reward the person who provided that answer with reputation points and you will also earn some reputation points (which can lead to other privileges on the site) for following the proper procedure and it creates a more valuable site for the long term as a repository of questions and good answers that are marked as so.

Answer (score 0):

`clearTimeout` doesn't stop the AJAX request, it only stops the it from being initiated. So if the user clicks the button while an AJAX request is running, your code will start a second one.

With the following code, if your AJAX request is already running, it will not start another one.

```
var rotate=0,
    running = false;

function refresh(){
    if (running === false){
        running = true;

        $.ajax({
        ...,
        success : function(data){
            running = false;

            $('#content-to-insert').html(data);
            rotate = setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
}

$('#user-refresh-btn').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(rotate);
    refresh();
});
```